# jQuery tabs, switching content - how not to break the back button?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have a jQuery tabs / content switcher and I'm trying to allow the use of the back button.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/k6CvX/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#gallery').css("display", "block");               //show first tab
    $(".tabs nav a").on("click", function(event){       //click a tab
        $('.tabs .tabContent').css("display", "none");  //hide all content boxes
        var clickedTab = $(this).attr('href');           //get the id from the href
        $(clickedTab).fadeIn();                          //show that content
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Currently, the ahref goes to #gallery, #recipes etc but this doesn't show in the URL bar of the browser because I have used return false to stop the page from jumping around.

I want people to be able to click the tab, or a link to another tab somewhere else in the page and be able to use their back buttons. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many, many useful plugins that exist on the web to help you achieve this functionality without going absolutely crazy. Some tap into browser history while others are more modern and leverage new technologies like local storage, sessions, etc.

Having said that, I know how frustrating it can be to post a question like this on stack and get this sort of reply, so... I went ahead and re-wrote much of your code to help you achieve what you are doing. Please note that the code below should not be considered a completely "full-proof" solution as it has its own downfalls with various browsers and etc. But, give it a shot and see if this will work for you so you can continue doing what it is that you need to do.

```
$(function () {
            var app = {
                    vars: {
                        gallery: $('#gallery'),
                        tabContent: $('.tabs .tabContent'),
                        nav: $('.tabs nav a')
                    },
                    events: function () {
                        //tabs
                        app.vars.nav.on('click', function (e) {
                            var thisHash = $(this).attr('href');
                            app.setHash(thisHash);
                            e.preventDefault();
                        });

                        //hashchange
                        $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
                            app.checkHash();
                        });

                    },
                    checkHash: function () {
                        var hash = app.getHash();

                        if (hash == '') {
                            app.vars.tabContent.hide();
                            app.vars.gallery.show();
                        } else {
                            app.goTo(hash);
                        }

                    },
                    getHash: function () {
                        return window.location.hash;
                    },
                    setHash: function (id) {
                        window.location.hash = id;
                    },
                    goTo: function (id) {
                        app.vars.tabContent.hide();
                        $(id).fadeIn();
                    }
                }
            app.events();
            app.checkHash();
        });
```

Paste all of that instead of your js above, and it should run as expected.

In a nutshell, the entire sequence of events (click and/or browser back/forward) is dependent on the `'hashchange'` event. It designates what should occur and how.

Once again, this is a potential solve for your question, however, please look into some more robust apps out there that are far more advanced and are capable of working on many different browsers.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is the *perfect* answer, thank you very much @spez86, really appreciate it.

As someone fairly new to JS, this really helps.